# Recursively find sum of digits including negative numbers

Tags: java, recursion

I'm working on a few challenges using recursion in Java (a new concept to me). I'm currently working on a recursive method that gives the sum of digits given a long parameter (n). Intended output:

- 257 = 14
- -257 = -14

I've tried editing my base case to include the numbers only between 1 & 10, then decrement the sum for `sumOfDigits()`, but obviously you cannot use an `if`, `else if`, or `else` statement in a recursive method. I am  stuck! Can someone steer me towards the solution? Here's my method:

```
    public static long sumOfDigits(long n){

    long sum = n %10;
    if ( n < 10){
        return sum;
    } else {
        return sum += sumOfDigits(n%10);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can you not use if, else if and else statements in a recursive method?

Comment: You are correct, thanks for your comment! You made me do some more digging and I solved my own problem.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone wondering, I managed to solve this myself!
Solution:

```
public static long sumOfDigits(long n){

    long sum = n %10;

    if (n == 0) return 0;

    if ( n >= 1 && n < 10){
        return sum;
    } else if (n < 0){
        return sum - sumOfDigits(-n %10);
    } else {
        return sum + sumOfDigits(n%10);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works by *coincidence*, not by *design*.  It simply returns twice the last digit.  But since the last digit of test number 257 equals the sum of the first two digits, it appears to work. Change the test number from 257 to 256 and instead of getting 13, you'll get 12 -- the last digit doubled.  Who upvoted this?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the solution is simpler than folks are trying to make it:

```
public static long sumOfDigits(long n) {

    long digit = n % 10;

    if (n == digit) {
        return n;
    }

    return digit + sumOfDigits(n / 10);
}
```

The sum in the `return` statement is independent of sign as you're either adding positives to positive or negatives to negatives.

The tricky part is the digit extraction and test -- it depends on Java's *remainder* operator (%) preserving the sign of the number on the left.  In some languages (e.g. Python) this is a *modulus* operator that always returns a positive result.  If you're working with a language with modulus, which doesn't preserve sign, you'll need a workaround for this (e.g. the `abs()` and/or `sign()` functions).

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
public class SumOfDigits {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("257 -> " + sumOfDigits(257));
    System.out.println("-257 -> " + sumOfDigits(-257));
    System.out.println("0 -> " + sumOfDigits(0));
    System.out.println("1 -> " + sumOfDigits(1));
  }

  public static long sumOfDigits(long n) {
    if (n < 0) {
      return sumOfDigitsOfPositive(Math.abs(n)) * -1;
    }
    else {
      return sumOfDigitsOfPositive(n);
    }
  }

  // Parameter n must be positive
  private static long sumOfDigitsOfPositive(long n) {
    if (n < 10) {
      return n;
    }
    else {
      long lastDigit = n % 10;
      return lastDigit + sumOfDigitsOfPositive(n / 10);
    }
  }
}
```